# Sonarqube not finding possible null pointer exception

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

In the below code, Why sonarqube is not finding possible null pointer exception in "updateData" method?

```
public class PropertyObject extends LinkedHashMap<String, Object> {

    /**
     * Unique serialization id.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4789053897514939L;

}

public class BaseObject extends PropertyObject {
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public String getId() {
        return String.valueOf(this.get("_id"));
    }

    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public void setId(Object id) {
        this.put("_id", String.valueOf(id));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return (String) this.get("name");
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.put("name", name);
    }
}

private void updateData(BaseObject baseObject) {
        List<Map<String, String>> link = (List<Map<String, String>>) baseObject.get("ratioMap");
            for (Map<String, String> linkmap : link) {

            }
        }
    }
```

I can see potential null pointer exception in updateData method in line number 2.
Is there any way by which I can make sonarqube to find these issues by itself?

Answer (score 0):

First of all Sonar is a static code analysis tool. It depends on simple declarations to look for possible NPEs. Second I assume that you have an active rule for detecting possible NullPointer dereferences.
Last but not least I think that it would not detect NPEs in private methods which is not called...